# Помогите разобраться с постановкой вопроса

Tags: грамматика, этикет

Здравствуйте! Сегодня у меня был вот такой диалог на форуме:
я: А можно поинтересоваться, какое у вас образование?
kogr: Поинтересоваться можно всегда. Вопрос в том, зачем?)

Человек на вопрос мне так и не ответил, ходил вокруг да около. Муж мне сказал, что я неверно задала первый вопрос. Надо было не писать "можно поинтересоваться..." а сразу спрашивать. Получается, что я спросила, можно ли, а человек и ответил, что можно.
Но! Он ведь не стал ждать моего вопроса! Он сразу поинтересовался "Зачем?". Т.е.он сознательно избегал ответа на вопрос.
Или я, действительно, неправильно сформулировала?

Answer (score 3):

И то, и другое.

Когда вопрос задаётся просто, без вступления (как "можно ли...", "не можете ли Вы..."), то может показаться грубоватым. "Можно поинтересоваться,..." высказывает вежливый и дипломатический тон и не выходит из нормы современной речи и письменного языка. Если придираться к словам, то так оно и есть - Вы спрашиваете о разрешении, не об образовании, и ответ Вашего собеседника вполне уместен с грамматической точки зрения. Но люди, отвечающие таким образом на вопросы, обычно либо просто чересчур придирчивы и нарочно делают вид, что не поняли о чём на самом деле спрашивают, либо избегают прямого ответа на вопрос. Хотя в принципе они и правы, но только из принципа цепляются за это вступление, поскольку такое выражение достаточно распространено и все прекрасно всё понимают.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: По этому поводу есть классический пример. В кафе посетитель за соседним столиком интересуется:
- Не могли бы Вы передать мне соль?
- Конечно, могу,- отвечает сосед, продолжая трапезу.

Comment: По  понятиям  уже  разговариваем.  Нормальный  посетитель  в  этом  случае  просит  или  спрашивает.  Вероятнее  -  просит.

Comment: "Не  могли  бы  вы ..." - это  одна  из  форм  вежливого  обращения, просьбы.  Вроде  бы  все  должны  знать.

Answer (score 0):

- Официант, можно мне кофе?
- - Откуда я знаю, можно вам кофе или нельзя)))

Comment: Официант  шутит.  Или  его  владение  русским  -  "только  со  словарём".